# Angular: Check values before pipe for correct type

Tags: angular

I have a value called `_myValue: string | undefined`.
I get it from the TS via getter:

```typescript
get myValue(): string | undefined {
    return this._myValue;
}
```

In the template I want to send it through a pipe.

```html
<td>
  {{ myValue| prinValues }}
</td>
```

### The problem:

**This pipe `prinValues`  only accepts `string | number` (no `undefined`).**

This of course leads to compilation problems. How can/should I ensure this? The pipe itself comes from an external library, so I won't be able to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to not render the element (or render a placeholder) when myValue is null or undefined:

```html
<td>
  <ng-container *ngIf="myValue">
    {{ myValue| prinValues }}          
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!myValue">
    no value        
  </ng-container>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the pipe is able to transform an empty string to a proper value, you can use [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to set the value to empty string if it's undefined:

```
get myValue(): string {
    return this._myValue ?? '';
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the approach from @Zerotwelve's answer.

Comment: possible he can not modify the .ts function but use this operator directly in template to pass empty string in case of undefined returned value

Answer (score 0):

Another inelegant solution is to disable the AoT template type-checking altogether using the [`$any()`](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any) function.

```html
<td>
  {{ myValue| $any(prinValues) }}
</td>
```

But as the documentation says, it only silences the type checking errors, and so renders the AoT template type-checking for that variable useless.